# What is the Tomcat directory /var/lib/tomcat7/common/ for?

Tags: tomcat

I'm upgrading a webapp server from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 8 on Ubuntu 16.04.  At installation, Tomcat 7 creates a directory `/var/lib/tomcat7/common/`.  When Tomcat 8 is installed, however, the `/var/lib/tomcat8/` directory it creates does not include a `common/` directory, and the deployment script complains that it isn't there.

```
build.xml:129: /var/lib/tomcat8/common/lib does not exist.
```

I've been searching for hours and have found exactly zero documentation on this, including on the official [8.0 migration guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html).

What is the `/var/lib/tomcat7/common/` for, and why does Tomcat 8 not have one?

Comment: Looks like a [legacy directory](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/tomcat-ug.html). On a tomcat 7 installation run `ls -l /var/lib/tomcat7` and check if `common` directory is a real one or a symbolic link.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz It's real, not a symlink.  Also, that link may not go where you intended it.  There's no mention of 'legacy directories' or a `tomcat/common/` directory on it.